# Swift plain style unsupported in a navigation item

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I am trying to animate my menu icon to when a user taps on the hamburger icon it will animate into a close icon.

So inside my navigation item I have a normal **Bar button Item** and inside that I have a **UIView** that I later animate.

But soon as I place the view inside the bar button item I get the warning:
*plain style unsupported in a navigation item*

Everything still works fine but how can I fix this?

I have seen other apps doing it like I do. eg: [this one](https://github.com/MengTo/DesignerNewsApp)

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying this in swift or objective-c?

Comment: @random right now I am trying swift, but I am open for any solution eg obj-c

Comment: I had the same issue and here is the link with good explanation how to fix it (it's not mine, I just think it's good enough to share it): http://blog.mosheberman.com/fixing-plain-style-unsupported-in-a-navigation-item-in-xcode-7

Answer (score 28):

So I found a solution.

If you set the **bar button item** to style > "bordered" the warning goes a away

Comment: Something is wrong with Xcode. I got this error but I see what I have to fix.. it says that it is Xcode but no clue where this problem is.